# Query xml using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, c#-4.0

i am new to xml queries. i have one xml like

```
<fields>
<fields name = "a" active ="1" mandat ="true"/>
<fields name = "a" active ="1"/>
</fields>
```

Now i need to find all the field names that manadt is true. How can i query xml using sql server. please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you happen to google something similar to 'SQL Server XML query'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear, especially the tags (`sql, xml, c#-4.0`), but from you question's text I take, that you need to query the XML's content within SQL-Server.

You can try it like this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<fields>
  <fields name="a" active="1" mandat="true" />
  <fields name="a" active="1" />
</fields>';

SELECT fld.value(N'@name',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Field_Name
      ,fld.value(N'@active',N'bit') AS Field_Active
      ,fld.value(N'@mandat',N'bit') AS Field_Mandant
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/fields/fields') AS A(fld)
```

The result

```
Field_Name  Field_Active    Field_Mandant
a           1               1
a           1               NULL
```

### UPDATE

If you want to read the value of `@name` of the fields-node, where `@mandat` is *"true"*, do it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<fields>
  <fields name="a" active="1" mandat="true" />
  <fields name="a" active="1" />
</fields>';

SELECT @xml.value(N'(/fields/fields[@mandat="true"]/@name)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Mandant_Name
```

### UPDATE 2: More than one `<fields>` with `@mandat="true"`

Just try my first solution with a predicate in `.nodes()`:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<fields>
  <fields name="a" active="1" mandat="true" />
  <fields name="b" active="2" />
  <fields name="c" active="3" mandat="false" />
  <fields name="d" active="4" mandat="true" />
</fields>';


SELECT fld.value(N'@name',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Field_Name
      ,fld.value(N'@active',N'bit') AS Field_Active
      ,fld.value(N'@mandat',N'bit') AS Field_Mandant
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/fields/fields[@mandat="true"]') AS A(fld)
```

This will return only the first and the last `<fields>` node

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer.

Comment: @kiran Please see my update. If this solves your issue, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the answer's vote counter. Thx!

Comment: Hi Shnugo, in my xml i have more than 2 fields where mandat="true". with the solution you provided i am getting only the first one. if you see my solution i got all the expected values.

Comment: @kiran The solution you provide does not work. There are various errors. Anyway, this can (and should!) be done easier. See my update 2

Comment: Thank you so much Shnugo. This worked for me. Thanks for your help.